# Apache Camel SFTP consumer with privateKeyFile gives error SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Protocol error: no matching DH grp found

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp, jsch

Unable to access SFTP location using Apache Camel with private key.

The SFTP URI: `sftp://user@host:22/usr/users/me/inbox/myfolder/?privateKeyFile=ssk-key.pem`

the key file is confirmed to be correct.

The error:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://user@host:22
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:146)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.connectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:203)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.doStart(SftpConsumer.java:52)
                at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3269)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3563)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3499)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3429)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3197)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3053)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2848)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2867)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
                at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2813)
                at org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:127)
                at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
                at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138)
                at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:390)
                at com.me.mypackage.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:27)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Protocol error: no matching DH grp found 
                at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:996)
                at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:323)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:118)
                ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: before trying the below, first check which Java version you're running on. If it's version 7 or earlier, try upgrading to a JRE 8 and see if the problem persists. Since answering this I've encountered as situation where things refused to work with Java 7, but worked fine with 8. It might have something to do with some default security provider settings.

---

Looking at the end of the stack trace, Camel is using the JSch library for FTP over SSH support. Knowing that can be useful in further troubleshooting, because you can look up which key exchange algorithms are supported by JSch.

When the client tries to establish a secure connection with the server, a list of supported algorithms is exchanged to figure out which algorithms both the client and server support. An algorithm is then chosen for the key exchange.

Judging by the error message returned from the server, the SFTP server is most likely using OpenSSH. The part where the error message is returned and the server disconnects is here in the OpenSSH source:

```
kex->dh = PRIVSEP(choose_dh(min, nbits, max));
if (kex->dh == NULL) {
    sshpkt_disconnect(ssh, "no matching DH grp found");
    r = SSH_ERR_ALLOC_FAIL;
    goto out;
}
```

"DH grp" means Diffie-Hellman group. Diffie-Hellman is a method of public key exchange. The groups determine which key-lengths are supported. Some examples:

- Group 1: 768-bit
- Group 2: 1024-bit
- Group 5: 1536-bit
- Group 14: 2048-bit

In the above bit of C code you notice that a DH group is searched for a minimum number of bits, a preferred number of bits (`nbits`) and a maximum number of bits. These numbers are provided by the client (JSch in Camel) to indicate what it supports. The server then seeks the best group. If it can't find any for these criteria, it disconnects with message `no matching DH grp found`.

You can find some info in this IETF memo: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4419. A relevant bit:

> 1. C sends "min || n || max" to S, indicating the minimal acceptable group size, the preferred size of the group, and the maximal group size in bits the client will accept.
> 2. S finds a group that best matches the client's request, and sends "p || g" to C.

C being the client and S the server.

So, what to do? First, check what the length is of the public key corresponding to your private key. Then request information regarding the supported **cipher algorithms**, **key exchange algorithms** and **DH groups** from whoever manages the SFTP server. It is possible that the server only supports groups with a higher minimum key than the key length you're using. Or the other way around: the client's public key is longer than the maximum supported by the server.

If the people on the server side are the type that install some package without really understanding what they're doing or configuring, you might have a hard time getting the info. In that case you might have some luck finding out about supported cipher and key exchange algorithms from both server and client by doing network packet capture (using a tool such as Wireshark), but be very careful about this. You'll want to get your superior's permission for this so it's not misconstrued as trying to defeat security measures or eavesdropping. The laws and their interpretation regarding this are slightly dumb in some countries, to put it mildly.

Depending on the outcome, the server might need to update their OpenSSH version, or configure it for additional DH groups; or perhaps you need to choose a key of a different length. Since that might affect the level of security you'd have to seek permission of the operators of the SFTP server and whoever you're doing a project for.

It looks like Camel allows you to specify which cryptographic ciphers to allow, with the `ciphers` option in the URI. If you don't specify it, the default list from JSch is used. Unfortunately I don't see an option to specify which key exchange algorithm to use. It looks like JSch does support many exchange algorithms (found it here under key exchange: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/README)

Try to find out which version of JSch your version of Camel uses. If you can update Camel and the newer version includes a newer JSch version, try that first. If you can't update or you're already on the latest version of Camel, see which version of JSch is included and if you can replace it with a newer release without breaking things. It's possible that the latest JSch release supports something that an older one didn't, and with the updates and deprecation of certain algorithms and key lengths due to security vulnerabilities, sometimes older versions of clients refuse to work with up-to-date servers (or the other way around).

Also look up how to enable logging in JSch (it seems that it doesn't use a default framework like Log4j or java.util.logging), and try setting the system property `javax.net.debug` to value `all` (for example, via command line parameter `-Djavax.net.debug=all`). It might supply extra info.

Good luck. I wish I could provide a specific solution, but issues like these often require communication between the SFTP server admin and the user to fix, since it involves knowing the configuration at both sides.